# Odoo How to use custom fields in the address layout

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I have inherited the res.partner model and added a custom field named "firm1"
Now, I need to display this field on every report in the address block.
To configure this I went to contacts > Countries > 'My Country' and tried to add my custom field like this:

[image: demonstration of how I tried to add the custom field]

however, when saving I get the message
"The layout contains an invalid format key"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to override either `res.partner._address_fields()` or `res.partner._formatting_address_fields()` to add your new field to the returned list of address field names.

Comment: Overwriting `res.partner._formatting_address_fields()` did the job. Thank you